# search for an specific character in each line in one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I want to search for subject fields having “Engineer” in it. Then,
calculate average number of papers for each engineering field and Display this table with total
authors within field information. can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
#use the Pandas library
import pandas as pd

#read in the data
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv') #read in the data
#add a new column that is 1 if 'Engineer' appears in the Subject Field, else 0
data['isEngineeringRelated']=data['Subject Field'].map(lambda x: 1 if 'Engineer' in x else 0)
#filter for engineering rows
engineering_data = data[data['isEngineeringRelated']==1]
#groupby the engineering fields and count the average number of papers of authors in that field
print(engineering_data.groupby('Subject Field')['Number of Papers'].mean())
```

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "Display this table with total authors within field information" - but perhaps this code can get you started.

I agree with Celius' comment by the way - in general it would be helpful to share an example dataset and to describe what you have tried already.